# Clojure: find the first occurence in a collection that passes predicate truth test

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

Is there a function in Clojure that works as described in the title:

Consider this vector:

```
(def v [{:a 0 :b 1} {:a 0 :b 3} {:a 0 :b 2}])
```

I'm, trying to catch the first entry, in which :b equals 3.

Usage would be like so: (this is how the JS-underscore find works)

```
(myfind #(= (:b %) 3) v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive solution:

```
(first (filter #(= (:b %) 3) v))
```

Idiomatic solution:

```
(some #(when (= (:b %) 3) %) v)
```

As a function:

```
(defn myfind [pred coll]                                                                                                          
  (some #(when (pred %) %) coll))

(myfind #(= (:b %) 3) v) => {:b 3, :a 0}
```

Comment: super, that's what I was looking for. the 2nd one is better, since it stops iterating once there is one result. I didn't know "some", just "some?". thank you!

Comment: There is nothing inefficient about `(first (filter` because it will be done lazily. i.e. the process will stop as soon as the first is found.

Comment: Actually 1st one is inefficient; namely creating a lazy sequence. Some just `recur`s. Moreover creating a lazy sequence just for the first item is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Anton:

You did not specific if you wanted to return the whole map that matches or some value for a key. Otherwise:

```
(filter #(= (:b %) 3)  [{:a 0 :b 1} {:a 0 :b 3} {:a 0 :b 2}])
=> ({:a 0, :b 3})
```